# Understanding candidate elimination algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to get to grips with how to do the candidate elimination algorithm by hand. I know the answer, but I dont the steps on how to get there. Can anyone guide me or point me in the right direction. Here is the question that I am working on:

```
Consider a concept description language with three attributes predened as follows:

attribute1      attribute2       attribute3
----------      ------------     ------------
|        |      |    |     |     |          |
a        b      c    d     e     f          g

Demonstrate version space learning using the following positive and negative training     examples:

1. ( a c f ) +)
2. ( b c f ) +)
3. ( a e g ) -)
4. ( a c g ) -)
5. ( b d f ) -)

Show how the candidate elimination algorithm changes the boundary sets after
processing each example.
```

This is what I have so far:

```
1. ( a c f ) +) Generalize..
G:(???)
S:(acf)

2. ( b c f ) +) Generalize...
G:(a??), (?e?), (?d?), (??g) - Not even sure if this is correct
S:(?cf)
```

Can someone guide me or give me advice please? Thanks

Comment: I have a lot of questions like this to revise for, but I dont know how to go about doing them. I just need a simple walkthrough with this example, and then I will be fine.

Comment: Fair enough. Don't you have professors or TA's to talk to? (I assume you are studying at a university or other place of higher learning.)

Comment: They are all away due to the festive period. Most will be back at work next week, and that is too late for me :(

Answer (score -1):

here: http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/ml/vspace/vs_prob1.html
this website really helps !

I made the tree for this exercise and the answer I got is G=S= (?cf)

it goes like this:

1. G: (???)
   S: (acf)

2.
G: (???)
S: (?cf)

1. G: (???)
   becomes 
   (b??),(?c?),(?d?),(??f)
   after pruning = 
   (?c?),(??f)
   S: (?cf)

4.
G: (?c?),(??f)
becomes (?cf),(??f)
(because (?c?) no longer holds for this example)
S: (?cf)

5.
G: (?cf),(??f) 
becomes (?cf),(?cf) 
(because < ??f > no longer holds for this example)
S: (?cf)

Final answer is:
G: (?cf),(?cf) = (?cf)
S: (?cf)

the final hypothesis is (?cf)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This really isn't an answer; it's a "me too!" sort of response.  If you're curious about the result, you can favorite it and keep an eye on it.  Otherwise, when you do have an answer, you can reply with your answer here. :)